# Output a comment in an XML file from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

How can I output to my textarea the content of a comment which is in my .xml file?

My .html:

```
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="3"/>
```

My .xml:

```
<div>
<ab type="transcription"><!--This is a comment--></ab>
</div>
```

My .js:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "../data/cards/1799.xml",
dataType: "xml",
cache: false,
success: function (xml) {
[...]
var mycomment = $(xml).find("ab").attr("type", "transcription");
$("comment").val(mycomment)
```

.text() doesn't output anything. Thanks in advance for any hint towards the right direction!

Comment: When you console.log(mycomment) in your success callback, do you get anything?

Comment: No, completely blank

Comment: PS: if I replace the xml comment with text, I get its output.. But I want the comment :) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML element is a `<textarea>`, not a `<comment>`, so `$('comment').val` won't work. Also, to get the text of the comment, you should use

```
$(xml).find('ab').text()
```

only - using `.attr` sets or gets the attribute of the node, which you don't care about. So, try:

```
const text = $(xml).find('ab').text();
$("#comment").val(text);
```

The `#` in front indicates that you want to find an element with that *id*. (without any symbols, you're indicate that you want to find an element with that *tag name*.)

In your XML, if you wanted to identify the `ab` whose type is `transcription`, you would use the query string:

```
ab[type="transcription"]
```

The other issue is that `text` (or `textContent`) doesn't identify comment nodes - but, if the `<ab>`'s content is only that comment, then you can use `.html` or `.innerHTML` to retrieve it.

Also note that there's no need to include a big library like jQuery just for this - you can achieve it quite easily in vanilla Javascript:

```
fetch(<url>)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then((text) => {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
    const text = doc.querySelector('ab').innerHTML;
    document.querySelector('#comment').value = text;
  });
```

Demo:

```js
const responseText = `<div>
<ab type="transcription"><!` + `--This is a comment--></ab>
</div>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(responseText, 'text/html');
const text = doc.querySelector('ab').innerHTML;
document.querySelector('#comment').value = text;
```

```html
<textarea id="comment"></textarea>
```

To access the content of the comment node, you can use `childNodes[0]` to navigate to the node, and then get its `textContent`:

```js
const responseText = `<div>
<ab type="transcription"><!` + `--This is a comment--></ab>
</div>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(responseText, 'text/html');
const text = doc.querySelector('ab').childNodes[0].textContent;
document.querySelector('#comment').value = text;
```

```html
<textarea id="comment"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks - yes, I do use the ab[type="transcription"], it's that I tried all sorts of mix and matches just to see if that made a difference. As I wrote in my original question, .text() doesn't work. It outputs proper text within the <ab> element, but ignores the comments. I want to output the text of the comment.

Comment: Ah, I see, it looks like you need to use `.html` or `.innerHTML` instead, see edit

Comment: .html does the job, thanks! :) a couple of related questions: how can I slice the beginning and the end so that I don't have the trailing <!-- and preprended --> without going through two steps (str.replace or str.slice, beginning first and then end)?

Comment: Also, and more importantly - the textarea is actually a wysiwyg editor which renderes italics, bold, etc. Is there any way to append the comment so that it gets properly rendered on the web page? Right now it outputs a italic with <i>text</i> (i.e. with lg; and gt;). Anything jquery/javascript can do about it?

Comment: See edit, of course you can also `slice` in one step, `str.slice(4, str.length - 3)`

Comment: No idea what editor you're working with, but it sounds like you want to use an option to insert HTML instead of the option to insert text?

Comment: I'm experimenting with summernote for the time being. For now I've done it with jquery just because I'm already using for other things and would need to refactor and revisit all the code, although I agree that put javascript would be much lighter. For now I've solved with

$('div.note-editable').html($.parseHTML(transcription));

Your answer definitely deserves the status of 'accepted', thanks for the hints and suggestions!